# Expect alternate solution to update the Dictionary with given reference dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to update the dictionary **"menu"** values by getting a value from an appropriate dictionary. I try the following code and get the desired result. But I expect some other alternate ways and a more generic solution in a pythonic way.

**Code**

```
language = {"english" : {"lbl01":"File"      ,"lbl02":"Accounts"},
            "tamil"   : {"lbl01":"கோப்பு"    ,"lbl02":"கணக்கியல்"},
            "hindi"   : {"lbl01":"Hindi_File","lbl02":"Hindi_accounts"}}

scut = {"user1": {"lbl01":"Alt+F","lbl02":"F5"},
        "user2": {"lbl01":"Ctrl+F","lbl02":"Shift+F5"}}

menu = {"lbl01" :{"id":"file"    ,"lan1":"","lan2":"","scut":""},
        "lbl02" :{"id":"accounts","lan1":"","lan2":"","scut":""}}

user = ["user2"]
selected_lan = ["tamil","hindi"]

menukey_lst,submenukey_lst =[],[]
for menukey,menuvalue in menu.items():
    if menukey not in menukey_lst: menukey_lst.append(menukey)
    for submenukey,submenuvalue in menuvalue.items():
        if submenukey not in submenukey_lst: submenukey_lst.append(submenukey)

for index,mk in enumerate(menu.keys()):
    for item in submenukey_lst:
            menu[menukey_lst[index]]["lan1"] = language[selected_lan[0]][menukey_lst[index]]
            menu[menukey_lst[index]]["lan2"] = language[selected_lan[1]][menukey_lst[index]]
            menu[menukey_lst[index]]["scut"] = (scut[user[0]][mk])

print(menu)
```

**Output**

```
{'lbl01': {'id': 'file', 'lan1': 'கோப்பு', 'lan2': 'Hindi_File', 'scut': 'Ctrl+F'}, `'lbl02': {'id': 'accounts', 'lan1': 'கணக்கியல்', 'lan2': 'Hindi_accounts', 'scut': 'Shift+F5'}}`
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```py
for key, value in menu.items():
    for sub_key in value.keys():
        if sub_key == 'lan1':
            value[sub_key] = language[selected_lan[0]][key]
        elif sub_key == 'lan2':
            value[sub_key] = language[selected_lan[1]][key]
        elif sub_key == 'scut':
            value[sub_key] = scut[user[0]][key]
```